# Launch application from VSCode

Tags: typescript, node-webkit, visual-studio-code

Is it in any way possible to launch an application from VSCode without also attaching to it for debugging purposes?

Currently I use nwjs to run a typescript application. I have set up a chrome debugger launch configuration in launch.json which works very well. However I dont always want to launch nwjs with the debugger attached. I just want to run my application. The reason for this is that I have multiple breakpoints which I dont want to disable every time I dont want them to be hit.

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes you can use tasks.json and define a task that will run your application. The same way as you setup your build or test tasks:

For example, tasks.json can look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node",
    "windows": {
        "command": "node.exe"
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "start.my.app",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/path/to/your/app.js"],
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a step on the way, however now this task runs every time I compile. I don't want that. (I have another task which compiles my typescript code.) I also need to be able to bind the execution of this new task to a key combo for efficiency.

Comment: If it runs every time you build (Ctrl+Shift+B) then you should set `"isBuildCommand": false` in task definition. So far its not possible to assign key shortcuts for individual task (only build and test tasks have dedicated key shortcuts) - but its on its way.

Comment: Thanks, this "isBuildCommand" only seems to available to sub tasks, which in this context seems a bit confusing to me. Could you please provide the full listing of how such a task would look. Also, when I add a new task to my tasks.json. I get an error "End of file expected" (tasks.json). I get this even though the syntax is correct JSON.

Comment: I have updated answer's sample. Under `tasks` property you can specify multiple tasks.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So how do I run this? It doesn't show in the task list. Nor does it run either ctrl+shift+t or ctrl+shift+b.

Comment: It should show up in the task list. Try restarting VSCode. Ctrl+shift+t or Ctrl+shift+b works only if you specify `isBuildCommand` or `isTestCommand` properties in tasks.